# PostGIS GML round trip confusion

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system, gml

I've investigated the issue of coordinate order in GML and each time I think I've got it but I find my self confused once again.

I think some of my confusion may be to do with PostGIS.  Doing a simple query on my database I can see the coordinates are stored correctly.  The st_asgml function is outputting these coordinates in long,lat order which I think is correct for this srsName:

```
select title, ST_AsGML(3, locationgeometry, 15, 1), xmin(locationgeometry), ymin(locationgeometry) from tblobject where title='Chuska East Ridge';
-[ RECORD 1 ]-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
title    | Chuska East Ridge
st_asgml | <gml:Point srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326"><gml:pos srsDimension="2">-108.848780000000005 36.078707000000001</gml:pos></gml:Point>
xmin     | -108.84878
ymin     | 36.078707
```

However, if I take the same GML output above and run it through st_geomfromgml, the coordinates appear to have been reversed:

```
select xmin(st_geomfromgml('<gml:Point srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326"><gml:pos srsDimension="2">-108.848780000000005 36.078707000000001</gml:pos></gml:Point>'));
-[ RECORD 1 ]---
xmin | 36.078707
```

Am I missing something, or is this a bug in PostGIS?  Can someone please confirm for me once and for all whether I should have lat,lon or lon,lat in GML when using the srsName urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326?

- PostgreSQL version: 9.1.14
- PostGIS version   : POSTGIS="1.5.3" GEOS="3.2.2-CAPI-1.6.2" PROJ="Rel. 4.7.1, 23 September 2009" LIBXML="2.7.8" USE_STATS

Comment: 'xmin' and 'ymin' don't look like a postgis functions. Could you please explain what are they? Why don't you use 'ST_X' and 'ST_Y' instead?

Comment: Yeah sorry - some lazy typing here.  You can substitute st_xmin and st_ymin or st_x and st_y but my point is the same.

Answer (score 2):

PostGIS typically expects coordinates in longitude-latitude or E-N order.

Looking at the second example from [**postgis.net/docs/ST_AsGML.html**](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsGML.html),
it seems there *is* some flipping of coordinates:

> ```
> -- Flip coordinates and output extended EPSG (16 | 1)--
> SELECT ST_AsGML(3, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(5.23423 6.34535)',4326), 5, 17);
>   st_asgml
>   --------
> <gml:Point srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326"><gml:pos>6.34535 5.23423</gml:pos></gml:Point>
> ```

And looking at an example in [wiki/Geography_Markup_Language#Point_Profile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geography_Markup_Language#Point_Profile), it seems GML does expect latitude-longitude or N-E ordering:

> ```
>  <name>Lynn Valley</name>
>  <description>A shot of the falls from the suspension bridge</description>
>  <where>North Vancouver</where>
>  <position>
>      <gml:Point srsDimension="2" srsName="http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/EPSG/0/4326">
>          <gml:pos>49.40 -123.26</gml:pos>
>      </gml:Point>
>  </position>
> ```

So, expect some flipping coordinate confusion between GML and PostGIS.

Comment: See also http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/4657 and http://blog.cleverelephant.ca/2007/12/lets-call-whole-thing-off.html for more discussion.

Comment: Argh.  I must find a whole day to sit down and really get my head around this again.  It stills seems there is no crystal clear solution to this though. :-(